# Dual boot Linux and Windows on RAID 1 drive

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, ssd, raid

I hope that this is the correct StackExchange to post this question.

I have got a new computer currently without any operating system installed. I have two identical Sata 1TB SSD cards and my intention is to mirror the two SSDs in RAID 1. At the same time I also want to have both Windows 10 and Linux installed and bootable off of that RAID 1 array (each OS getting one partition).

TL;DR - I basically have two identical Sata SSDs and want to have dual boot Win 10 and Linux while also mirroring the drives for data redundancy.

Unfortunately I am currently unable to get any more storage drives or a hardware raid card. And installing one OS on each of the drives wouldn't give me data redundancy.

Edit:
Actually after some more searching, I was able to find something called BIOS RAID. From what I understand I could activate that in RAID 1 and then first install Windows and then Linux, as BIOS RAID will make my two drives show up as a single drive to whatever OS I am using. Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: Hey Custos! Which OS do you refer by "*Linux*"? Are you talking Ubuntu or Fedora or Debian or something else?

Comment: @technastic_tc sorry for not specifying. I was thinking of Ubuntu.